# Error while generating excel from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel

I have simple code for generating Excel which loops and produces excel sheet.

```
        Excel.Application XlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
        Excel.Worksheet Ws = null;

        XlApp = new Excel.Application();
        XlApp.Visible = true;
        workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

        workbook.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value,Missing.Value,  
        6, Missing.Value);

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
             Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[j];
             Ws.Activate();
             Ws.Name = SheetName.ToString();//Sheetname has a Name 
        }
```

Now the problem is When we run this code everything works fine. But sometimes what happens is, at the client side one of the sheet name is not generated it skips. So our solution to them is to try generating the sheet again and then it works fine,
So my question is why does the code skip the sheetName (**sometimes**), although there is no problem in the code. Does it have to do anything with clients other running processes?

Comment: What is `SheetName` object?

Comment: It is a String object

Comment: swap the two lines.Assign the sheetname first and activate it.

Comment: are you sure you have more than or equal 7 Worksheets? and why you call `Activate`? try without it

Comment: Well, you have an object count = 6 within Add method and you go 7(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) time with your for loop. 
Try to go through that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Excel.Application XlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
Excel.Worksheet Ws = null;

XlApp = new Excel.Application();
XlApp.Visible = true;
workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

// here you get the first ws, index 1
Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

workbook.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
6, Missing.Value);

var SheetName = "sheet_";
// here you should start from 1 (not from 0) and include 7 in the loop count
for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
{
    // make sure that the ws name is unique
    SheetName=String.Format("sheet_{0}",j);
    Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[j];
    Ws.Activate();
    Ws.Name = SheetName;// this is already a string
}

XlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Does it work on the same computer where it's also not working?

Comment: Do you have any `try{}catch{}` statements which wraps your code?